# API not hitting when building apk and run it on another device

Tags: flutter, dart, nodejs-server, flutter-apk

I am working on the flutter project. I hosted my backend server and got the IP. When I use that I to run the project on debug mode it hitting the API but when I build the apk and run it on the other device It is not hitting the API. How can I resolve this issue?

Frontend: Flutter + Dart
Backend: NodeJS + MongoDB

Comment: do you have internet permission in your AndroidManifezt.xml? like this:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> you should add it to it if you don't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in the android manifest file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
Credit: Godson